# What is the inverse of a triangular matrix whose nonzero elements are binomial coefficients? What is the closed-form solution to a recursive relation?

Tags: matrix-analysis, matrix-inverse, difference-equations, finite-differences, recursively-enumerable

Let
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
M_m
&=\begin{pmatrix}
-\binom{1}{0} & \binom{2}{0} &-\binom{3}{0} &\dotsm & (-1)^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{0} & (-1)^m\binom{m}{0}\\
0 & \binom{2}{1} &-\binom{3}{1} &\dotsm & (-1)^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{1} & (-1)^m\binom{m}{1}\\
0 & 0 &-\binom{3}{2} &\dotsm & (-1)^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{2} & (-1)^m\binom{m}{2}\\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\dotsm & (-1)^{m-1}\binom{m-1}{m-2} & (-1)^m\binom{m}{m-2}\\
0 & 0 & 0 &\dotsm & 0 & (-1)^m\binom{m}{m-1}
\end{pmatrix}_{m\times m}\\
&=(M_{i,j})_{m\times m},
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
where
\begin{equation*}
M_{i,j}=
\begin{cases}
(-1)^{j}\dbinom{j}{i-1}, & 1\le i\le j\le m;\\
0, & 1\le j<i\le m.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
For $m=5$, by the famous software Mathematica, we obtain
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
 0 & 2 & -3 & 4 & -5 \\
 0 & 0 & -3 & 6 & -10 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 & -10 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -5 \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
 -1 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{6} & 0 & \frac{1}{30} \\
 0 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -\frac{1}{5} \\
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
What is the inverse of the triangular matrix $M_m$ for $m\in\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\dotsc\}$?

The matrix $M_m$ comes from the recursive relation
\begin{equation}\label{beta(m+1minus1)}
\sum_{k=j+1}^{m}(-1)^{k}\binom{k}{j}\beta_{m+1,k}
=(-1)^{j+1} \beta_{m,j}, \quad 0\le j\le m-1,
\end{equation}
where the first few $\beta_{m,j}$ are
\begin{align*}
\beta_{1,0}&=1, & & & & & &\\
\beta_{2,0}&=\frac{5}{3}, & \beta_{2,1}&=1, & & & &\\
\beta_{3,0}&=\frac{11}{5}, & \beta_{3,1}&=\frac{13}{6}, & \beta_{3,2}&=\frac{1}{2}, & &\\
\beta_{4,0}&=\frac{93}{35}, & \beta_{4,1}&=\frac{101}{30}, & \beta_{4,2}&=\frac{4}{3}, & \beta_{4,3}&=\frac{1}{6}.
\end{align*}
We can also derive
\begin{align*}%\label{beta(m+1)m-form}
\beta_{m,m-1}&=\frac{1}{(m-1)!}, \quad m\ge1,\\
\beta_{m,m-2}&=\frac{3m+4}{6(m-2)!}, \quad m\ge2,\\
\beta_{m,m-3}&=\frac{15 m^2+35 m+24}{120(m-3)!}, \quad m\ge3,\\
\beta_{m,m-4}&=\frac{105 m^3+315 m^2+364 m+176}{5040(m-4)!}, \quad m\ge4.
\end{align*}
We guess that
\begin{equation*}
\beta_{m,m-k}=\frac{1}{(2k-1)!(m-k)!}\sum_{\ell=0}^{k-1}\theta_{k,\ell} m^\ell, \quad m\ge k,
\end{equation*}
where $\theta_{k,\ell}$ is a sequence of positive integers.

What is the explicit or closed-form expression of the sequence $\theta_{k,\ell}$ for $0\le\ell\le n-1$?
What is the explicit or closed-form expression of the sequence $\beta_{m,j}$ for $0\le j\le m-1$?

Comment: Numerics suggest that that this inverse is [Faulhaber's triangle of fractions](https://oeis.org/A162299) or some straightforward modification of it -- I'd look through the references of that linked OEIS entry.

Comment: Let's forget $(-1)^j$ because it's easily handled. Then your matrix represents the linear transformation $f \mapsto (x+1)f(x+1)-xf(x)$ on the space of polynomials of degree $<m$. To find the inverse, you have to solve the deifference equation $g(x+1)-g(x)=x^j$.

Comment: @NarutakaOZAWA Could you please write out more details?

Comment: @NathanielJohnston You are right. Thank you for your valuable comment.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see how you get the $\beta_{m,j}$ from the recursion relation without specifying, e.g., $\beta_{m,0}$.

Comment: @FredHucht I regard the recursive relation as a system of linear nonhomogeneous equations of $\beta_{m+1,j}$ for $1\le j\le m$ and write it as a matrix form with the coefficient matrix $M_m$ and the vector $(\beta_{m,0},\beta_{m,1},\dotsc,\beta_{m,m-1})$.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. However, with your definition the matrix $M_m$ has to be applied to the vector $(\beta_{m+1,1},\ldots,\beta_{m+1,m})$, and therefore $\beta_{m+1,0}$ is not used. Consequently, the inverse $M_m^{-1}$ cannot reconstruct $\beta_{m+1,0}$. See also my comment below.

Comment: @FredHucht Your observation about $M_m^{-1}$ and $\beta_{m,0}$ is right.

Comment: So, will you clarify your question?

Comment: @FredHucht I have no any more to clarify. From the recurrence relation given in the question, some explicit formula for the sequence $\beta_{m,j}$ or the sequence $\theta_{k,\ell}$ should be derived.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not possible, as the  system of equations resulting from the given recursive relation is underdetermined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may answer the question, the sequence is the only implicit thing. I consider $Q=\begin{pmatrix}Q_{i,j}\end{pmatrix}_{n\times n}$ for $n\ge 3$, where
$$Q_{i,j}=
\begin{cases}
\dbinom{j}{i-1}, & 1\le i\le j\le n;\\
0, & 1\le j<i\le n.
\end{cases}
$$
This is the same as the one defined in the question up to multiplying it by a $\pm 1$ diagonal matrix.
Define sequence $u_k$ by $u_1=1$ and
$$
u_k=-\sum_{i=0}^{k-2}\dfrac{u_{i+1}}{(k-i)!}
$$
for every $k>1$. The $n\times n $ matrix $Q^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}q_{i,j}\end{pmatrix}_{n\times n}$ is given by
$$
\begin{cases}
q_{i,j}=0,&1\le j<i\le n;\\
q_{i,i}=\dfrac{1}{i},&1\le j=i\le n;\\ 
q_{i,i+1}=-\dfrac{1}{2},&2\le j=i+1\le n;\\
q_{i,i+k}=u_{k+1}(i+1)\cdots(i+k-1),&k+1\le i+k\le n, k\ge 2.
\end{cases}
$$
The proof is formal and should be direct, also the sequence $u_k$ has some zero entries.

Comment: This is not a direct answer to the question.

Comment: The inverse of $_$ should be $^{−1}_=\begin{pmatrix}(−1)^iq_{,}\end{pmatrix}_{\times }$. Is there an explicit expression of the sequence $_$?

Comment: Hi, ok for the edit and the expression of $M_m^{-1}$, i just kept the 'multiplying of a diagonal matrix $D$' as $(QD)^{-1}=D^{-1}Q^{-1}$. For the sequence i don't think so (i am not an expert in that).

Comment: Dear Toni, could you please give a reference of your answer?

Comment: I just computed the equations and got the identites, we compute the first diagonal of the upper triangular $Q^{-1}$ (easy) then the second, then the third (off) diagonal etc. the induction would appear and could be verified.

Answer (score 4):

Using the answer of @Toni, the sequence $u_k$ can be related to the Bernoulli numbers $B_k$ for $k\geq 0$,
\begin{align}\tag{1}
u_{k+1}= \frac{B_{k}}{k!}.
\end{align}
After some algebra, the inverse of $M_m$ is given by
\begin{align}\tag{2}
M_m^{-1} = \left[ \, (-1)^i \binom{j}{i} \frac{B_{j-i}}{j} \, \right]_{i,j=1}^{m}
\end{align}
for $m>0$.

Comment: Dear Fred, you are right, I derived the same result from the identity $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+1}{k}B_k=\delta_{n,0}.$$ What is the explicit expression of the sequence $\beta_{m,j}$?

Comment: I don't see the precise relation between $M_m$ and the recursion, please recheck. Either, in the definition of $M_m$ index $j$ must be shifted by one to run from $0,\ldots,m-1$ and it should read (-1)^{i-j}, or the recursion for $\beta$ is not correct.